# Render widget script in Angular 5 html view

Tags: angular, widget, angular5

I am using Angular 5 JS and all project template is created by Angular cli. I am trying to add widget script in component HTML view. But it is not rendering, where as in index.html it is working fine.

Here is my HTML view with widget script

```
<p> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript">   new TradingView.widget(
    {"width": 980,
    "height": 610,
    "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "Light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,"hideideas": true});   
    </script>' </p>
```

I am new to Angular 5, so I do not know the way, how to render script widget to Angular 5 view.

Here is complete component.ts file code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ngEmbed } from 'ng-embed';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tradingchart',
  templateUrl: './tradingchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tradingchart.component.css']
})

export class TradingchartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {


  }
  ngOnInit() {
    new TradingView.widget(//this code line producing error
      {"width": 980,
      "height": 610,
      "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "Light",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,"hideideas": true});
  }
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922256/embed-widgets-in-angular-2-component-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed widgets in Angular 2 component template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922256/embed-widgets-in-angular-2-component-template)